# Bash output data to file

Tags: c, bash, append, output

I have compiled C file, named `a.out` which I run with  `time ./a.out`

This gives me this output:

```
Values in data mining increases by 30 in 100 seconds

real    5m3.898s
user    4m3.889s
sys     3m0.008s
```

I have made a script to automate this:

```
#!/bin/bash

time /home/full.sh >> /home/data.txt
```

but in my `data.txt` file, I only see this (and not the time data):

```
Values in data mining increases by 30 in 100 seconds
```

Comment: @terencehill that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get both time and script output you can use this

```
 { time script; } &> outputfile
```

note the `&` sign